# How do i get the return value coming a database with just using return?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need to get the value returned from a stored procedure in my Sql Server db.a This store procedure using a return statement to return a value back to the app.

I need to retrieve this value in C#. How do i get this value?

Note:

- I know i can use ExecuteScalar while using "select ..." in the sp to retrieve this value.
- I also know i can use a output variable.
- What is don't know is how to retrieve the value returned from a return statement in my sp.

How do i get it done? I am avoid make a lot of change.

**Update**:

I'm using **SQLHelper**.

Comment: I've just checked the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749622/ado-net-how-to-get-return-value-of-a-stored-procedure it does not solve my problem cause im using sqlhelper. So the question is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a parameter to the query using `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue` for the paremeder `Direction` property.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749622/ado-net-how-to-get-return-value-of-a-stored-procedure).

Comment: You should be a lot more explicit.

Comment: You are asking me to be more explicit - how? What more information do you need?

Comment: @Oded Perfect...I was just digging for this "explicit" answer.

Answer (score 3):

Set your return parameter's `Direction` property to `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`, and after you execute your command get return parameter's value like that :

```
SqlParameter myReturnParam = command.Parameters.Add("@MyReturnValue", 
                                                      SqlDbType.Int);
myReturnParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

// Execute your Command here, and get the value of your return parameter : 
int myReturnValue = (int)command.Parameters["@MyReturnValue"].Value;
```

Comment: I'm still get 0 has the return value. I'm using SqlHelper.