# Get return values from a stored procedure in c# (login process)

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, authentication, return-value

I am trying to use a Stored Procedure which takes two parameters (login, pw) and returns the user info.

If I execute the SP manually, I get

```
Session_UID   User_Group_Name      Sys_User_Name    
------------------------------------ -------------------------------------------------- -
NULL            Administrators       NTMSAdmin
No rows affected.
(1 row(s) returned)
@RETURN_VALUE = 0
Finished running [dbo].[p_SYS_Login].
```

But with the code below, I only get the return value. 
do you know how to get the other values shown above like 
Session_UID, User_Group_Name, and Sys_User_Name ?

if you see the commented part below code. I tried to add some output parameters but it doesn't work with incorrect number of parameters error.

```
            string strConnection = Settings.Default.ConnectionString;            
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    SqlDataReader rdr = null;
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.CommandText = "p_SYS_Login";
                    //cmd.CommandText = "p_sys_Select_User_Group";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    SqlParameter paramReturnValue = new SqlParameter();
                    paramReturnValue.ParameterName = "@RETURN_VALUE";
                    paramReturnValue.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
                    paramReturnValue.SourceColumn = null;
                    paramReturnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

                    //SqlParameter paramGroupName = new SqlParameter("@User_Group_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                    //paramGroupName.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                    //SqlParameter paramUserName = new SqlParameter("@Sys_User_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                    //paramUserName.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramReturnValue);

                    //cmd.Parameters.Add(paramGroupName);
                    //cmd.Parameters.Add(paramUserName);

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sys_Login", textUserID.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sys_Password", textPassword.Text);

                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        object result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        int returnValue = (int)cmd.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"].Value;
                        if (returnValue == 0)
                        {
                            Hide(); 
                            Program.MapForm.Show();
                        }
                        else if (returnValue == 1)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("The username or password you entered is incorrect", "NTMS Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                        }
                        else if (returnValue == 2)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("This account is disabled", "NTMS Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                        }
                        else                         
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Database error. Please contact administrator", "NTMS Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string message = ex.Message;
                        string caption = "MAVIS Exception";
                        MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.OK;

                        MessageBox.Show(
                            message,
                            caption,
                            buttons,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Warning,
                            MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                    }                    
                }
            }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call [ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader%28VS.90%29.aspx) method on the cmd object and read the output by using Read method of the [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) class.

Here is an example: [SqlDataReader.Read method.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with Try with `ParameterDirection.Output`?

```
 SqlParameter paramReturnValue = new SqlParameter();
 paramReturnValue.ParameterName = "@RETURN_VALUE";
 paramReturnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

 ...

 conn.Open();
 cmd.Connection = conn;
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

 ...

 int returnValue = (int)cmd.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"].Value;
```

If your SP uses an OUT parameter, like this:

```
 CREATE PROC FOO(@bar INT OUT) AS
 SELECT @bar = 1
```

Then you need to use the `ParameterDirection.Output` when setting up your SqlCommand object.

However, if your SP uses the RETURN keyword, like this:

```
 CREATE PROC FOO(@bar INT OUT) AS
 RETURN 1 -- NOTE the RETURN
```

Then you have to use `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`. I suspect the former case is the good one.

See [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749622/ado-net-how-to-get-return-value-of-a-stored-procedure)