# Return value indicating update success/failure of SQL Server stored procedure via ADO/VBA

Tags: vba, stored-procedures, ado, return-value

I have a SQL Server 2008 stored procedure that updates values in a table. I would like to have the stored procedure return an integer value indicating that the update was successful (return 0) or not (returns error number). What would be the best way to accomplish this via ADO and VBA? Here some of my code in simplified form that performs the update ... I am just not sure how to get back the return value of the stored procedure

```
Public Function DoUpdate(employeeID as integer, firstName as string, lastname as string) as integer

  Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
  Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
  Dim activeConnectionString As String

  activeConnectionString = GetActiveConnectionString()

  Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
  cnn.ConnectionString = activeConnectionString
  cnn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
  cnn.Open

  Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
  cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
  cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
  cmd.CommandText = "uspUpdateEmployeeName"
  cmd.NamedParameters = True

  cmd.Parameters("@EmployeeID").Value = employeeID 
  cmd.Parameters("@FirstName").Value = firstName
  cmd.Parameters("@LastName").Value = lastName

  cmd.Execute

  'Unsure of how to get back return value here
  'DoUpdate = returnValue

  Set cnn = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use

```
Dim lngRecs As Long

cmd.Execute lngRecs
```

lngRecs should contain records affected.

Answer (score 5):

Note: The **`return_value`** must be the **first parameter!**

Order matters.

I was getting errors stating that my query `"had too many arguments"` when I had specified my `return_value` parameter last, instead of first.

The parameters' ordering was the cause of my error.

Answer (score 2):

I seem to remember that you need to supply an extra parameter with the type 'adParamReturnValue' like this:

```
Dim lRetVal as Long

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("returnvalue", adInteger, adParamReturnValue)

cmd.Execute

'Now check the return value of the procedure
lRetVal = cmd.Parameters("returnvalue")

If lRetVal > 0 then
```

Answer (score 2):

Several ways are possible to get values back using VBA:

1. Recordset
2. Count of records affected (only for Insert/Update/Delete otherwise -1)
3. Output parameter
4. Return value

My code demonstrates all four. Here is a stored procedure that returns a value:

```
Create PROCEDURE CheckExpedite
    @InputX  varchar(10),
    @InputY int,
    @HasExpedite int out
AS
BEGIN
    Select @HasExpedite = 9 from <Table>
    where Column2 = @InputX and Column3 = @InputY

    If @HasExpedite = 9
        Return 2
    Else
        Return 3
End
```

Here is the sub I use in Excel VBA. You'll need reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library.

```
Sub CheckValue()

    Dim InputX As String: InputX = "6000"
    Dim InputY As Integer: InputY = 2014

    'open connnection
    Dim ACon As New Connection
    'ACon.Open ("Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=<SqlServer>;" & _
    '    "Initial Catalog=<Table>;Integrated Security=SSPI")

    'set command
    Dim ACmd As New Command
    Set ACmd.ActiveConnection = ACon
    ACmd.CommandText = "CheckExpedite"
    ACmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

    'Return value must be first parameter else you'll get error from too many parameters
    'Procedure or function "Name" has too many arguments specified.
    ACmd.Parameters.Append ACmd.CreateParameter("ReturnValue", adInteger, adParamReturnValue)
    ACmd.Parameters.Append ACmd.CreateParameter("InputX", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, InputX)
    ACmd.Parameters.Append ACmd.CreateParameter("InputY", adInteger, adParamInput, 6, InputY)
    ACmd.Parameters.Append ACmd.CreateParameter("HasExpedite", adInteger, adParamOutput)

    Dim RS As Recordset
    Dim RecordsAffected As Long

    'execute query that returns value
    Call ACmd.Execute(RecordsAffected:=RecordsAffected, Options:=adExecuteNoRecords)

    'execute query that returns recordset
    'Set RS = ACmd.Execute(RecordsAffected:=RecordsAffected)

    'get records affected, return value and output parameter
    Debug.Print "Records affected: " & RecordsAffected
    Debug.Print "Return value: " & ACmd.Parameters("ReturnValue")
    Debug.Print "Output param: " & ACmd.Parameters("HasExpedite")

    'use record set here
    '...

    'close
    If Not RS Is Nothing Then RS.Close
    ACon.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Set RS = ACmd.Execute(RecordsAffected:=RecordsAffected) works like a charm!