# Get Value of Primary key generated by stored procedure in VB

Tags: sql, vb.net

Note: this stored procedure is in use by the company and I can't change it.

Here is part of the stored procedure:

```
    DECLARE @tmp_PERSON TABLE(PERSON_PK INT);
        INSERT INTO [Ks4_ENTITY_PERSON]
                   ([TITLE_FK]
                   ,[INITIALS]
                   ,[FIRSTNAME]
                   ,[MIDDLENAME]
                   ,[KNOWNAS]
                   ,[SURNAME]
                   ,[GENDER_FK]
                   ,[DATEOFBIRTH]
                   ,[HOME_LANGUAGE_FK]
                   ,[IDNUMBER_TYPE_FK]
                   ,[IDNUMBER]
                   ,[MATURITY_FK]
                   ,[MARITAL_STATUS_FK]
                   ,[MARITAL_DATE]
                   ,[MARITAL_REGIME_FK]
                   ,[CITIZENSHIP1_COUNTRY_FK]
                   ,[CITIZENSHIP2_COUNTRY_FK]
                   ,[TAX_NUMBER]
                   ,[SUFFIX_FK]
                   ,[SALUTATION_FK]
                   ,[RESIDENT_COUNTRY_FK]
                   ,[IS_PENSIONER]
                   ,[OCCUPATION_FK])
             OUTPUT inserted.PERSON_PK INTO @tmp_PERSON <---- THIS LINE??!?
             VALUES
                   (@TITLE_FK
                   ,@INITIALS
                   ,@FIRSTNAME
                   ,@MIDDLENAME
                   ,@KNOWNAS
                   ,@SURNAME
                   ,@GENDER_FK
                   ,@DATEOFBIRTH
                   ,@HOME_LANGUAGE_FK
                   ,@IDNUMBER_TYPE_FK
                   ,@IDNUMBER
                   ,@MATURITY_FK
                   ,@MARITAL_STATUS_FK
                   ,@MARITAL_DATE
                   ,@MARITAL_REGIME_FK
                   ,@CITIZENSHIP1_COUNTRY_FK
                   ,@CITIZENSHIP2_COUNTRY_FK
                   ,@TAX_NUMBER
                   ,@SUFFIX_FK
                   ,@SALUTATION_FK
                   ,@RESIDENT_COUNTRY_FK
                   ,@IS_PENSIONER
                   ,@OCCUPATION_FK)
```

How can I get the value `PERSON_PK` that was inserted into that `@tmp_PERSON`
from my VB app?

NOTE: `@tmp_Person` is a on the fly declared table, not a predefined `@VAR OUTPUT` type

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to create and retrieve data from an output parameter in VB.NET:

```
Private Function test()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Your_SP_Name_Here", _
                                  New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("your_conn_settings_id").ConnectionString)) 'This SQL Connection should be replaced with a connection specific to your SQL Server
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@PERSON_PK", SqlDbType.SmallInt, Nothing).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        End With

        Dim newid As Integer = 0

        Try
            cmd.Connection.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            newid = cmd.Parameters("@PERSON_PK").Value

        Catch sql_ex As SqlException
            cmd.Connection.Close()
            cmd = Nothing
            Throw sql_ex
        Catch ex As Exception
            cmd.Connection.Close()
            cmd = Nothing
            Throw ex
        End Try

        cmd.Connection.Close()
        cmd = Nothing

        Return newid ' <-- YOUR NEW ID IS HERE
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change your stored procedure to return @@identity (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx) you can then use this article to update your VB code to get the value [How to get a return value from a stored procedure in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650894/how-to-get-a-return-value-from-a-stored-procedure-in-vb-net)