# Executenonquery return value

Tags: asp.net, return-value, executenonquery

I want to perform a search on a table to see if record exists. I do not want to perform insert or update after. I have done this already but somehow I cannot get this to work. On my asp.net page I cannot seem to get any value returned. The error is "input string not in correct format" I ma sure it is obvious but I cannot seem to see it now!

here is my code:

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection("connstring")
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("checkname", con)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@d", SqlDbType.Int))
cmd.Parameters("@id").Value = TextBox1.Text

Dim para As New SqlParameter
para.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
para.ParameterName = "returnvalue"
cmd.Parameters.Add(para)

con.Open()


cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Dim exists As Integer
exists = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters("returnvalue").Value)
If exists = 1 Then
    Label1.Text = "You......"
         ElseIf exists = 0 Then
    Label1.Text = "You....."

End If
con.Close()
```

stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE checkname 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @id int
AS
  --This means it exists, return it to ASP and tell us
 -- SELECT 'already exists'

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM attendees WHERE id = @id)
BEGIN
RETURN 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   RETURN 0
END
```

Comment: On which line is the error thrown? Can you use SQL Profiler to determine the call that is being made onto the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that you are passing an integer.

```
int intValue;
if(!int.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out intValue))
{
     // Update your page to indicate an error

     return;

}

cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("id", SqlDbType.Int));
cmd.Parameters("id").Value = intValue;
```

(Technically you don't need the "@" character when
   defining the parameters in the .NET
   code.)

Comment: for sql server you do need the @ symbol when defining parameters

Comment: @Charles - you need the @ in the Transact-SQL code, but not in the ADO.NET code. Try it and see.

Comment: "d" was a typo, in my code it is id. I tried removing the @ and included the Integer. Parse but still got the same error result. "input string was not in the correct format.

Comment: @Andrew - I sit corrected. I didn't know about this. How long has this been the case?

Comment: @Andrew - TBH i did test it before I wrote the comment. However the code I changed was using SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters() which does add an @ symbol to the parameters. So I guess in some places it is still required when accessing the parameters collection of the DbCommand object.

Comment: when I insert the following convert.toint Line 17: cmd.Parameters("@id").Value = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text) I get the error input value not in correct format. If i leave it as textbox1.text only the input error is at the line containing cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: @mick - AHA. The contents of TextBox1.Text is not an integer. I'll update my answer.

Comment: excellent! that solved that problem but now I am only getting a return value of 0.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared your procedure parameter as @d instead of @id. Also a return parameter cannot be an input parameter. The return value should be an exit code. You most likely want to create an output parameter and set that to 1 or zero inside of your stored procedure.

Edit: to clarify, the return value is generally regarded as an indicator of correct execution. Zero usually means success, where any other numeric value is generally regarded as an error code. That is why I recommended adding an output parameter instead of adding a return value parameter.

Comment: Also you need to convert the id to an int before setting the command parameter value.

Comment: I don't think your correct regarding the output parameter. Mick is correctly setting the parameter direction to "ReturnValue". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749622/ado-net-how-to-get-return-value-of-a-stored-procedure

Comment: you must make a parameter specifically for capturing a return value. it cannot be used as an input, output or combination thereof.

Comment: I set the output parameter in sp and it works: @ailaid int, @val int OUTPUT AS IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM attendees WHERE id = @id) BEGIN SET @val = 1 END ELSE BEGIN SET @val = 0 END                                how do I call it from asp.net?

Comment: create a parameter and set the Direction = ParameterDirection.Output. Then call it as before with ExecuteNonQuery. Then you can get the parameter value by accessing cmd.Parameters("@val").Value to get your returned value

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int)) cmd.Parameters("@id").Value = TextBox1.Text cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@val", SqlDbType.Int)) cmd.Parameters("@val").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output con.Open() cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() Dim exists As Integer exists = cmd.Parameters("@val").Value If exists = 1 Then Label1.Text =                                                                                    I still get the input error. Maybe I coded it wrong?

Comment: Your code looks correct. I would use Andrew's suggestion of using TryParse() to verify the value of your TextBox before calling the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of rows affected.  Therefore the return values that you set in your stored procedure are thrown away and will not be returned by the `ExecuteNonQuery` method.

Comment: From MSDN "Although the ExecuteNonQuery returns no rows, any output parameters or return values mapped to parameters are populated with data."

Answer (score -2):

ExecuteNonQuery is used to Insert / Delete / Update operations. Not for SELECT, you need either ExecuteScalar or ExecuteReader methods. This link will help you to know how to use output parameters : http://aspdotnet-suresh.blogspot.com/2010/10/introduction-here-i-will-explain-how-to.html

Comment: He isn't calling SELECT, he is invoking a stored procedure. If the stored procedure was providing information via a select statement, then ExecuteScalar or ExecuteReader would be appropriate. As the stored procedure is only returning a value, ExecuteNonQuery is appropriate.

Comment: out parameters are frequently used to return a single record when it is known that only one record will ever be returned (e.g. selecting based on the primary key)