# SQL Server stored procedure return value, and using it in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, webforms

My application allows the user to add a new player to the database. Before adding a new player, I'd like for a stored procedure to check whether or not a player with the first name and last name exists. I want the stored procedure to return a `bit` value, `0` or `1`. My C# method will then return this value and the program can decide whether or not to proceed with the creation.

Note that I've cut some of the general validation out of the code below, i.e. if the fields are empty, or the balance TextBox is invalid etc..

I'm also aware that I may be using the wrong datatype when handling the returned value. i.e. `int` instead of `bool`.

When I run this, I get an error saying that my SP requires an input parameter `@ReturnedValue`.

Cheers

```
 Player newPlayer = new Player();
 newPlayer.PlayerID = Guid.NewGuid();
 newPlayer.FirstName = TextBoxFirstName.Text;
 newPlayer.LastName = TextBoxLastName.Text;
 newPlayer.Balance = Convert.ToDouble(TextBoxInitialCredit.Text);

var exists = newPlayer.CheckExists();

if (exists == 1)
{
     newPlayer.AddPlayer();
}
```

and here's the method:

```
 public int CheckExists()
 {
     SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Badminton"].ConnectionString);

     myConnection.Open();

     SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand("CheckPlayerExists", myConnection);
     SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

     SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = FirstName;
     SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = LastName;
     SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int, 2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

     SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlCmd);
     DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
     myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);

     int exists = Convert.ToInt32(SqlCmd.Parameters["@ReturnValue"].Value);

     myConnection.Close();

     return exists;
 }
```

and now my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CheckPlayerExists
   @firstName nvarchar(50),
   @lastName nvarchar(50),
   @ReturnValue bit output
AS 
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Players WHERE FirstName = @firstName AND LastName = @lastName)
        SET @ReturnValue = 1
ELSE
        SET @ReturnValue = 0

RETURN @ReturnValue
END
```

Comment: you should use `FirstName = @firstName OR LastName = @lastName`

Comment: A DataTable would be simpler than a DataSet.

Comment: You don't need a table, set or adapter as there are no rows in the output, ExecuteNonQuery would be simplest, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630002/executenonquery-return-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there's some inconsistency in your posted information.  Is the parameter `@ReturnValue` or `@ReturnedValue`?  That alone could be the problem.

Second, either change your stored procedures declaration of the `@ReturnedValue` parameter to

```
@ReturnValue bit = 0 output
```

or change the C# code that adds the output parameter:

```
SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter();
p.ParameterName = "@ReturnedValue";
p.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
p.Value = 0;
p.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
SqlCmd.Parameters.Add(p);
```

Comment: Thanks RBarry. I had only changed it from atReturnValue to atReturnedValue following an earlier answer. My original code was fine. The problem was your second suggestion. I needed to add '= - output' to the parameter declaration within the SP. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** You are assigning the `ParameterDirection` Enum value as `Output`.

**Solution :** Change your `ParameterDirection` Enum  value from `Output` to `ReturnValue`

**ReturnValue:** [ParameterDirection.ReturnValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.parameterdirection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The parameter represents a return value from an operation such as a
>   stored procedure, built-in function, or user-defined function.

Replace This:

```
SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int, 2).Direction
   = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

With This:

```
SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int, 2).Direction
   = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

Comment: Thanks, i've changed that as well as the SP to @ReturnedValue, however I receive this error: Procedure or function 'CheckPlayerExists' expects parameter '@ReturnedValue', which was not supplied

Comment: @ManxJason: did you  change the direction parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I think I see your issues.  In the line:

```
SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int, 2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

change name and direction type to:

```
SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnedValue", SqlDbType.Int, 2).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

Comment: Thanks, i've changed that as well as the SP to @ReturnedValue, however I receive this error: Procedure or function 'CheckPlayerExists' expects parameter '@ReturnedValue', which was not supplied.

Comment: Did you change the `ParameterDirection` from `.Output` to `.ReturnValue`?