# Returning a custom value from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this store procedure;

```
USE [DataBase]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[DeleteAll]    Script Date: 05/09/2011 00:18:00 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteAll]
    @theID uniqueidentifier
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    BEGIN TRY

        DELETE FROM Table1
        WHERE ID = @theID    

        DELETE FROM Table2
        WHERE ID = @theID    

        DELETE FROM Table3
        WHERE ID = @theID

    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
            BEGIN 
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            END
    END CATCH;

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
        BEGIN
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
        END
END
```

It’s possible to return an integer depending on the result??

For example:  1 for success, 2 for the catch.

Thanks in advance!

Edgar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Use the [`RETURN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx) statement and check the return value [in your client code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749622/ado-net-how-to-get-return-value-of-a-stored-procedure).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE checkstate @param varchar(11)
AS
IF (SELECT StateProvince FROM Person.vAdditionalContactInfo WHERE BusinessEntityID = @param) = 'WA'
    RETURN 1
ELSE
    RETURN 2;
GO
```

Comment: wouldn't 0 and 1 be more appropriate return values? As in, Zero equals False, > 0 equals True

Comment: @Mitch - Agreed. The code sample was taken verbatim from MSDN... feel free to change it.

Comment: Damn you MSDN!!! Wish they would stop making updating MSDN a summer intern task! (I'm guessing!)

Comment: @Mitch - didn't know that was the case. Though it does explain a lot.

Comment: Thanks! that work. The reason for 2, instead of 0, is because I manage the errors differently. For me, 0 is an "expected Error", and I use 2 for unexpected Errors.