# Seems like My stored procedure is returning Integer

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have done my stored procedure 101 recently and just wrote a little stored procedure, which looks like following:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectProUserByUsername]
    @userName varchar(300)
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;   
    SELECT * from ProUser
END
```

For some reason, SSMS has a reason to believe that my return type is integer. It should in object browser that my stored procedure returns integer[image: Return integer]

I am not sure what is the reason why it does that. Any ideas?

Comment: Someone can probably write this up as an answer with references if I'm right, but I think the key here is that a *procedure* doesn't really have a return value, but a *function* does. The integer "returned" is presumably referring to the exit status the proc can set. The actual result set just pops out asa side effect of running the sproc, and isn't "returned" in the usual programming sense.

Comment: @IMSoP: I see, you mean this is just an indicator indicating that whether or not the procedure exited properly or not.. Is that correct understanding?

Comment: It's not whether the procedure executed: it's the number of rows in the result set.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Hm, I could be wrong, but I assumed it was the value given to `RETURN x`; see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932951/returning-a-custom-value-from-stored-procedure?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server supports both [User-Defined Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191007.aspx) and [Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190782.aspx). Whereas a function takes a number of parameters as input, and returns a single value of a user-defined type as output, a stored procedure is simply a set of connected SQL statements. They can be connected to the rest of the program via input and output parameters, or they can simply modify data, produce result sets, etc, as though the Transact-SQL had been pasted directly into the query.

To quote [the Books Online article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190782.aspx), a stored procedure can:

- Accept input parameters and return multiple values in the form of output parameters to the calling program.
- Contain programming statements that perform operations in the database. These include calling other procedures.
- Return a status value to a calling program to indicate success or failure (and the reason for failure).

That last point is the sense in which a stored procedure "returns an integer", because the return status is always an integer value (with a default of 0). This is controlled by using [the `RETURN` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx) inside the stored procedure.

For instance, if I ran your stored proc above like so:

```
DECLARE @return_status int;
EXEC @return_status = SelectProUserByUsername 'IMSoP';
SELECT @return_status as status;
```

I would get an additional result set with `status` of `0`; if I added `RETURN 1` at the end of the procedure, I would get `1` instead.

SSMS is simply displaying the "return type" to be consistent with functions, but it's always going to be an integer for a stored procedure.

Note that in some contexts, an integer-returning function and a stored procedure could be used interchangeably; for instance [the `EXECUTE`/`EXEC` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) in my example above uses the same syntax for any "module" (procedure, function, etc).