# How to check whether stored procedure executed successfully

Tags: stored-procedures, vb6, ado

If you have a stored procedure that executing multiple queries, doesn't return values and doesn't have error-handling in it, how can you ascertain whether the stored procedure ended successfully when calling from VB code?

For example, if the stored procedure is something like:

```
create stored procedure some_procedure
    Insert  into ...
    delete ...
    update ... 
end
```

... and the VB code is like this:

```
Cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
Cmd.CommandText = "some_procedure"
Cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
Set rs = Cmd.Execute
Debug.Print rs(0)
```

... then how can I get a return value that is `0` for success or `1` for failure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a value from stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596662/how-to-get-a-value-from-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0):

I believe passing the optional RecordsAffected parameter with the Execute statement will work for you. Since you're so scarce on the details you'll have to try it, but this has worked for me with SQL, and FoxPro OLEDB providers. Also, why no error handling? IMHO not having an error handler in code that has a good possibility of producing an error is asking for trouble.

```
...
Dim lngRecsAffctd As Long

Cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
Cmd.CommandText = "some_procedure"
Cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
Cmd.Execute lngRecsAffctd, ,adCmdStoredProc   'why set to a recordset when the sproc doesn't return anything?
Debug.Print lngRecsAffctd
...
```

The complete details of the Execute command and the RecordsAffected parameter can be found at [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)