# SQL Server stored procedure result returned

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_AVAILABLE_PLACES] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@eventGuid uniqueidentifier,
@placeGuid uniqueidentifier,     
@dateGuid dateTime 
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- Insert statements for procedure here
DECLARE @ReservedPlaces int;
DECLARE @TotalPlaces int;    
SELECT @ReservedPlaces = RESERVED_PLACES FROM dbo.EVENT_DATE_PLACE
WHERE EVENT_GUID = @eventGuid 
and DATE_BEGIN = @dateGuid
and PLACE_GUID = @placeGuid    
SELECT @TotalPlaces = NUMBER_PLACES FROM dbo.PLACES
WHERE GUID = @placeGuid    
RETURN @TotalPlaces - @ReservedPlaces;     
END
```

But I can not seem to read the result returned

```
private int SelectByStoredProcedureGetAvailablePlaces(string entryParam1, string entryParam2, DateTime entryParam3)
{
        int results;
        //PlanningElement plan = GetPlanningElement(entryParam1, entryParam2, entryParam3.ToString(), "31/12/2012 00:00:00", "150");

        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
            sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;

            sqlCommand.CommandText = "GET_AVAILABLE_PLACES";
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("eventGuid", entryParam1);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("placeGuid", entryParam2);                
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("dateGuid", entryParam3);

            sqlConnection.Open();

            SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            results = sqlDataReader.GetInt32(0);

            sqlConnection.Close();
        }

        return results;
    }
```

What is the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: The reader reads rows, not return codes. Your existing code will work if you replace the `RETURN @TotalPlaces - @ReservedPlaces;`   with `SELECT  @TotalPlaces - @ReservedPlaces;`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749622/how-to-get-return-value-of-a-stored-procedure shows alternatives

Answer (score 2):

The `GetInt32` method will read from a selected table output. You want a return value, so you can change the code to be

```
SqlParameter returnValueParam = sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int);
returnValueParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(returnValueParam);
...
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
result = returnValueParam.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can alter your stored procedure, replace

```
RETURN @TotalPlaces - @ReservedPlaces;
```

By:

```
SELECT (@TotalPlaces - @ReservedPlaces) AS [AvailablePlaces]
RETURN;
```

Your can also get a return value from your stored procedure, but that requires some more modifications. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706361/getting-return-value-from-stored-procedure-in-c-sharp) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

That particular type of return value must be read by using an additional parameter in the SqlCommand.Parameters collection with direction of System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue

To read it as you are attempting, your SQL procedure would need to do:

```
SELECT @TotalPlaces - @ReservedPlaces As MyResult
```

Then the result will be returned as a resultset instead of a return value.

Answer (score 0):

So my stored procedure must be as this ?

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_AVAILABLE_PLACES] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@eventGuid uniqueidentifier,
@placeGuid uniqueidentifier,     
@dateGuid dateTime 
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- Insert statements for procedure here
DECLARE @ReservedPlaces int;
DECLARE @TotalPlaces int;    
SELECT @ReservedPlaces = RESERVED_PLACES FROM dbo.EVENT_DATE_PLACE
WHERE EVENT_GUID = @eventGuid 
and DATE_BEGIN = @dateGuid
and PLACE_GUID = @placeGuid    
SELECT @TotalPlaces = NUMBER_PLACES FROM dbo.PLACES
WHERE GUID = @placeGuid    
SELECT @TotalPlaces - @ReservedPlaces As ReturnValue;   
END
```

And my function as this ?

```
private int SelectByStoredProcedureGetAvailablePlaces(string entryParam1, string entryParam2, DateTime entryParam3)
{
        int results;
        //PlanningElement plan = GetPlanningElement(entryParam1, entryParam2, entryParam3.ToString(), "31/12/2012 00:00:00", "150");

        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
            sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;

            sqlCommand.CommandText = "GET_AVAILABLE_PLACES";
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("eventGuid", entryParam1);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("placeGuid", entryParam2);                
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("dateGuid", entryParam3);

            SqlParameter returnValueParam = sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int);
            returnValueParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(returnValueParam);

            sqlConnection.Open();

            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            result = returnValueParam.Value;

            sqlConnection.Close();
        }

        return results;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in yourth strored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_AVAILABLE_PLACES] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@eventGuid uniqueidentifier,
@placeGuid uniqueidentifier,     
@dateGuid dateTime,

@ReservedPlaces int output,
@TotalPlaces int output   

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- Insert statements for procedure here

SELECT @ReservedPlaces = RESERVED_PLACES FROM dbo.EVENT_DATE_PLACE
WHERE EVENT_GUID = @eventGuid 
and DATE_BEGIN = @dateGuid
and PLACE_GUID = @placeGuid    
SELECT @TotalPlaces = NUMBER_PLACES FROM dbo.PLACES
WHERE GUID = @placeGuid    
SELECT @TotalPlaces - @ReservedPlaces As ReturnValue;   
END
```

And this in your programm

```
private int SelectByStoredProcedureGetAvailablePlaces(string entryParam1, string   entryParam2, DateTime entryParam3)
{
        int results;
        //PlanningElement plan = GetPlanningElement(entryParam1, entryParam2, entryParam3.ToString(), "31/12/2012 00:00:00", "150");

        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
            sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;

            sqlCommand.CommandText = "GET_AVAILABLE_PLACES";
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("eventGuid", entryParam1);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("placeGuid", entryParam2);                
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("dateGuid", entryParam3);

            SqlParameter returnValueParam = sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int);
            returnValueParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            sqlConnection.Open();

            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            result = returnValueParam.Value;

            sqlConnection.Close();
        }

        return results;
```