# How to obtain returned scalar value of a Stored Procedure using dapper

Tags: sql-server, store, dapper

I am very new to dapper-dot-net and I am trying to call a Stored Procedure called **esp_TRV_PERIODO_MES_CRU** which returns an **int** which is the **IdPeriodo** of the inserted/existing/updated record

**Please do not remove the comments in my code since they show other approaches that I have tried but not succeded**

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[esp_TRV_PERIODO_MES_CRU]
        @anio = 2017,
        @mes = 12,
        @mesCerrado = NULL

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

I have the following (non-working) implementation

```
public Tescalar ExecuteScalar<Tescalar>(string spName, DynamicParameters p)
{
    Tescalar resp ;

    resp = default(Tescalar);

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {

            connection.Open();
            resp = connection.ExecuteScalar<Tescalar>(spName, p, null, connection.ConnectionTimeout, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            //connection.Execute(spName, p, null, connection.ConnectionTimeout, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
        return resp;
    } 
}
```

And I am calling the above method like this:

```
public Int32 ConsultarPeriodoMes(int anio, int mes)
{
    Int32 idPeriodo;
    DynamicParameters parametros;
    DynamicParameters resp;

    parametros = new DynamicParameters();
    parametros.Add("@anio", anio);
    parametros.Add("@mes", mes);
    parametros.Add("@mesCerrado", null);

    //idPeriodo = GetDataBaseHelper().ExecuteProcedureNonQuery("esp_TRV_PERIODO_MES_CRU", parametros);

    //resp = GetDataBaseHelper().ExecuteProcedure("esp_TRV_PERIODO_MES_CRU", parametros);
    //idPeriodo = -999;

    idPeriodo = GetDataBaseHelper().ExecuteScalar<Int32>("esp_TRV_PERIODO_MES_CRU", parametros);



    return idPeriodo;
}
```

I have tested the Stored Procedure **esp_TRV_PERIODO_MES_CRU** and is returning the expected **idPeriodo** of the INSERTED/FOUND/UPDATED entity, here is the SP

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[esp_TRV_PERIODO_MES_CRU]
@anio INT,
@mes INT,
@mesCerrado BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
    @idperiodo AS INT

    --Verfica si el periodo existe, dado los parametros anio y mes 
    SELECT @idperiodo = ISNULL((SELECT IdPeriodoMes FROM TRV_PERIODO_MES(NOLOCK) WHERE Anio=@anio AND Mes=@mes),-1)

    IF @idperiodo > -1
        UPDATE [dbo].[TRV_PERIODO_MES]
        SET [CierreEjecutado] = ISNULL(@mesCerrado, 0)
        WHERE IdPeriodoMes = @idperiodo
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO TRV_PERIODO_MES VALUES(@anio,@mes,ISNULL(@mesCerrado, 0))
        SET  @idperiodo = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    END

    RETURN @idperiodo
END
```

What do I need to fix in order to be able to obtain the returned value of the Stored Procedure shown above using dapper-dot-net

Comment: I just found this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749622/how-to-get-return-value-of-a-stored-procedure - but not sure how to apply that same idea using dapper

Answer (score -2):

Also you can use DynamicParameters.

```
using (IDbConnection con = new SqlConnectionFactory().Create())
        {
            var p = new DynamicParameters();

            //parameters
            p.Add("@x", valueX);
            p.Add("@y", valueY);

            //return value
            p.Add("@idperiodo", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);

            //PSET_SOURCEEVENT - name of procedure
            con.Execute("PSET_SOURCEEVENT", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            con.Close();
            return p.Get<int>("@idperiodo");
        }
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. Rather post this as a comment.